# Optimize lens based JSON handling

Tags: json, haskell, aeson, lenses

In my current "learning haskell" project I try to fetch weather data from a third party api. I want to extract the `name` and `main.temp` value from the following response body:

```
{
  ...
  "main": {
    "temp": 280.32,
    ...
  },
  ...
  "name": "London",
  ...
}
```

I wrote a `getWeather` service to perform IO and transform the response to construct `GetCityWeather` data:

```
....

data WeatherService = GetCityWeather String Double
    deriving (Show)

....

getWeather :: IO (ServiceResult WeatherService)
getWeather = do
  ...

  response <- httpLbs request manager

  ...

  -- work thru the response
  return $ case ((maybeCityName response, maybeTemp response)) of
    (Just name, Just temp) -> success name temp
    bork                   -> err ("borked data >:( " ++ show bork))

  where
    showStatus r    = show $ statusCode $ responseStatus r
    maybeCityName r = (responseBody r)^?key "name"._String
    maybeTemp r     = (responseBody r)^?key "main".key "temp"._Double
    success n t     = Right (GetCityWeather (T.unpack n) t)
    err e           = Left (SimpleServiceError e)
```

I stuck optimizing the JSON parsing part in `maybeCityName`, and `maybeTemp`, my thoughts are:

1. Currently the JSON is parsed twice (I apply `^?` two times on the raw response `responseBody r`).
2. I would like to get the data in "one shot". `?..` is able to get a list of values. But I extract different types (`String`, `Double`) so the `?..` does not fit here.

I'm looking for more elegant / more natural ways to safely parse JSON, read desired the values and apply them to the data constructor `GetCityWeather`. Thanks in advance for any help and feedback.

Update: using Folds I am able to solve the problem with two case matches

```
getWeather :: IO (ServiceResult WeatherService)
getWeather = do
  ...
  let value = decode $ responseBody response
  return $ case value of
    Just v -> case (v ^? weatherService) of 
        Just wr -> Right wr
        Nothing -> err "incompatible data"
    Nothing     -> err "bad json"

  where
     err t = Left (SimpleServiceError t)

weatherService :: Fold Value WeatherService
weatherService = runFold $ GetCityWeather
  <$> Fold (key "name" . _String . unpacked)
  <*> Fold (key "main" . key "temp" . _Double)
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken your question is just about how to efficiently extract those values from the JSON type (using lens). In that case I think you should remove the whole web request part from your question as it is not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jpath point out, the real problem you have here is one about `lens` and JSON handling. The crux of the issue seems to be that you want to do the lens operation all at once. For that, check out the handy [`ReifiedFold`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Combinators.html#t:ReifiedFold): the "parallel" functionality you want is packed into the `Applicative` instance.

```
import Control.Lens
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Lens
import Data.Text.Lens ( unpacked )

-- | Extract a `WeatherService` from a `Value` if possible
weatherService :: Fold Value WeatherService
weatherService = runFold $ GetCityWeather
  <$> Fold (key "name" . _String . unpacked)
  <*> Fold (key "main" . key "temp" . _Double))
```

Then, you can try to get your `WeatherService` all at once:

```
...
-- work thru the response
let body = responseBody r
return $ case body ^? weatherService of
  Just wr -> Right wr
  Nothing -> Left (SimpleServiceError ("borked data >:( " ++ show body))
```

However, for the sake of error messages, it might be a better idea to take advantage of `aeson`'s `ToJSON`/`FromJSON` if you plan on scaling this more.

Comment: Hi Alec, thank you very much for this solution! It feels much cleaner than mine. I observed that the type of `weatherService` is not correct `Couldn't match type ‘Value’ with ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString’`. When I remove the type declaration ghci inference works it out correctly and the program compiles. But, I'm wondering which part I should adopt to explicitly state the type of `weatherService`: (a) adopt `weatherService :: Fold ...ByteString ...` or should I (b) transform the `body` into a `Value`? Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions!

Comment: Oops! You should transform the body into a `Value`. I'm not longer sure how the code in your question compiles though... Isn't `response` there just a bytestring too? Perhaps you've elided some parsing? :D

Comment: Allright, I think I am able to decode the JSON, unfortunately this gives me another Case-Match (json decoding may fail) [see updated question] I try to get my head around all the concepts I'm learning; but I'm not able to flatten out the structure into a flat case match; Do you have an idea / help for me?

Comment: You can flatten a `Maybe (Maybe a)` with `Control.Monad.join`. However, in your case, I'd prefer to leave the two cases separate a give them different error messages; one case indicates invalid JSON, the other indicates JSON not matching the expected schema.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thank you very much for your help!